# How tight should brake lever clips be?

Tags: handlebars, brake-levers

I've ordered some second-hand handlebars from one seller on eBay, and brake levers from a different seller. Both claim to be 22.2mm diameter but the clip on the levers (as photographed) will be a very tight fit if it will fit at all.

Am I right in thinking that the clip as photographed doesn't come apart into any other pieces?

The levers do say 22.2, I can't find any markings on the bars. Am I right in thinking that 22.2mm bars and 22.2mm levers go together?

---

[image: clip flush with end of handlebar]
Figure 1. Clip is flush with end of handlebar

---

[image: clip raised slightly from end of handlebar]
Figure 2. Clip raised slightly from end of handlebar

Comment: The steel of those clamps is quite malleable, and it looks to me like they can be easily spread to fit around the bar.  (One observes that the clamp is not circular, and spreading it a bit would likely make it closer to a circle.)

Comment: Based on the shadows, the second photo shows the clip held above the bar end by ~5 mm whereas the top photo is even with the bar end.    The photos are misleading, sorry.

Comment: @Criggie I've added proper captions to the photos now, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

The clamps most probably got a bit squished in the mail. You should be able to make them a bit larger with a pair of needlenose pliers.

I would try expanding them (without the tightening bolt) so that they fit over, then bringing the two arms together with the pliers and putting the bolt in.

Comment: I've spoken to the seller this evening and they've said that the bars aren't 22.2, probably more like 23 or 24. It might be a bit of a stretch!

Comment: Nothing that a dremel tool (or file) and a bit of elbow grease couldn't make fit. :-)